# Java generic class, inner class using parameter of outer class

Tags: java, generics

I have outer generic class which has some inner class, for which I'd like to use the generic type of outer class.

However, I don't understand how to use generic parameters correctly.

Example:

```
class Outer<E extends CharSequence>{
   class Inner extends ArrayList<E>{
   }

   void func() {
      ArrayList<CharSequence> al = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
      al.add("abc");    // OK
      CharSequence a = al.get(0);   // OK

      Inner in = new Inner();
      in.add("abc"); // Error: The method add(E) in the type ArrayList<E> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
      CharSequence b = in.get(0);   // OK
   }
}
```

How can I declare inner class to use same generic type of outer class?
Thanks

**EDIT + Solution:**

Finally I achieved what I wanted, here's example result:

```
abstract class MyGenericClass<E extends CharSequence>{
   class TheList extends ArrayList<E>{};

   TheList list = new TheList();
}

final class ClassInstance extends MyGenericClass<String>{
};

public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ClassInstance c = new ClassInstance();

      c.list.add("abc");
      String s = c.list.get(0);
   }
}
```

My requirement was to have generic class, and also have generic container in it, which would use same type parameter as its parent class.

*Note: CharSequence/String are example parameters of use, my real usage is different.*

Comment: The usage of Inner in func() is raw, It should be Inner<E> in = new Inner<E>();

Comment: @AllenParslow: Wrong.  `Inner` is not generic.

Comment: `E` is already available to your inner class.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do.  Of course `in.add("abc")` fails, `"abc"` is not of type `E` (at least as far as the compiler is concerned; this isn't C++).  So looks like you should make an `Inner<String>` instead inside of `func`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I declare inner class to use same generic type of outer class?

`Inner`  is already using the same generic type as `Outer`. The problem is that `func` is not using it, it is using `CharSequence`.

As SLaks [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13404383/18573) `func` will do funky stuff in all cases except when it is called on an `Outer<CharSequence>`: e.g. when called on `Outer<String>` it will add a `CharSequence` to an `ArrayList<String>`.

Now, if `func` *already* had an object of that concrete type:

```
void func(E e) 
{
    Inner in = new Inner();
    in.add(e);
}
```

It would do the right thing. So the compiler allows this.

It seems you tried to create a generic question from some specific issue you are facing. If you described what you are trying to do and failing you will have better chance of resolving it here.

Answer (score 4):

That is fundamentally unsafe.

What would happen if I make an `Outer<StringBuilder>`?
You would end up adding a `String` to an `ArrayList<StringBuffer>`.

If you have a collection of `<E extends CharSequence>`, the only type-safe thing you can put in that collection is an instance of `E`  (or a class that extends `E`, or `null`).

Comment: Actual types are not relevant here, String/Charsequence are examples, I work with other class hierarchy in my project, where I want to make this work.

Comment: @mice: That's still unsafe.  `String` is just an example.  See my last paragraph.

Answer (score -3):

```
 class Inner extends ArrayList<CharSequence>{
 }
```